# Shadow Jar add two JDBC drivers to one jar file with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jdbc, jar, build.gradle

I am encountering an issue when I try to build a fat jar file with gradle. Is there a way to configure gradle to support multiple JDBC drivers in the JAR file? I noticed in my `META-INF/services/java.sqlDriver` that it will take whatever JDBC library comes first. So when running the jar file I would often see this error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:299)
```

I see that the solution to this issue revolves around adding `Class.forName('jdbcDriver')` before I initialize my db connections, but I see that for JTDS libraries you do not need that anymore because of JDBC type 4 can automatically detect which driver you need based on the connection string.

My build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id("application")
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.0"
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'net.sourceforge.jtds', name: 'jtds', version: '1.3.1'
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.26'
}
```

My connection string

`jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1111/db;user=TEST;password=DUMMY`

I am using Java 17 and Gradle 7.3.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the Gradle Shadow Plugin to merge the provider-configuration files. How to do that is [documented here](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/merging/#merging-service-descriptor-files):

> ### Merging Service Descriptor Files
>
> Java libraries often contain service descriptors files in the `META-INF/services` directory of the JAR. A service descriptor typically contains a line delimited list of classes that are supported for a particular *service*. At runtime, this file is read and used to configure library or application behavior.
>
> Multiple dependencies may use the same service descriptor file name. In this case, it is generally desired to merge the content of each instance of the file into a single output file. The `ServiceFileTransformer` class is used to perform this merging. By default, it will merge each copy of a file under `META-INF/services` into a single file in the output JAR.
>
> ```
> // Merging Service Files
> shadowJar {
>   mergeServiceFiles()
> }
> ```
>
> The above code snippet is a convenience syntax for calling `transform(ServiceFileTransformer.class)`

If using the Kotlin DSL, it would look like:

```
tasks {
    shadowJar {
        mergeServiceFiles()
    }
}
```

Or:

```
tasks.shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}
```